# The intersection of powersets is contained in the powerset of intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove or Disprove: For any family of sets $\{A_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$

$$\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\mathcal P \left({A_n}\right)\ = \mathcal P \left({\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n}\right)$$

How do I approach proving this? I know how to unpack the definition of powersets ($\mathcal P \left({A}\right) = \{x | x \subseteq A\}$) but I'm not sure what else I can do. I've done powerset proofs before but none involving indexed family of sets.

Comment: How would you unpack $\;\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty\;$ using the definitions?  In other words, $\;x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n \;\equiv\; \ldots\;$?  Oh, and the definition of $\;\subseteq\;$.  Once you know those, you can unpack both $\;X \in \text{LHS}\;$ and $\;X \in \text{RHS}\;$ see how to prove the resulting expressions equivalent for all $\;X\;$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let

$$\begin{cases}A = \displaystyle\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty \mathcal{P}(A_n) \\
B = \mathcal{P}\left(\displaystyle\bigcap_{i=1}^\infty A_n\right)
\end{cases}$$

Then if $S\in A$ we have that $S\subseteq A_i$ for all $i$ therefore $S\subseteq \cap A_n$, hence $S\in B$ by definition, proving the result.

Answer (score 0):

If $X\in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \mathcal{P}(A_n)$ we want to show $X\subseteq\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$.  To show this we want to show that if $x\in X$ then $x\in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty A_n$.  Since you ask how you can approach the problem, perhaps this is enough to get you started.